# Accidently renamed the libc library file

Tags: solaris, boot

I accidently renamed libc library in solaris 10 machine.. commands are not working..IS there any way to restore system back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a live CD, mount the partition and rename libc back to its original name.

Answer (score 4):

You don't say which version of solaris 10 -

- x86 at the grub screen boot `Solaris Failsafe`. This should mount your existing root filesystem on /a so you can go to /a/lib and rename the file(s) as appropriate.
- sparc put a Solais Sparc installation CD (DVD) in the drive and from the OK prompt `boot -s cdrom`. When you get to the miniroot mount your existing filesystem onto the miniroot and then rename the files(s) as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it'll work with solaris' runtime linker, however I've recovered from a similar situation on linux by forcing the runtime linker to load the renamed libc with LD_PRELOAD and then running mv to rename it back to what it was supposed to be. ([Man ld.so.1](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19253-01/816-5165/ld.so.1-1/index.html) for solaris does seem to indicate the presence of a LD_PRELOAD environment variable that does what we want)

```
LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/libc.so.renamed mv /path/to/libc.so.renamed /path/to/libc.so.correct
```

This assumes you still have a shell on the system.